# Convert String to byte[] in Android

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I want to convert the string of path image to byte array and than to convert it to Bitmap.

I have error:

```
09-25 09:38:11.050:
W/System.err(21261): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
09-25 09:38:11.350: 
W/System.err(21261): at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
09-25 09:38:11.350: 
W/System.err(21261): at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
09-25 09:38:11.350:
W/System.err(21261): at com.up.upload.MainActivity.UploadImage(MainActivity.java:186)
09-25 09:38:11.350: 
W/System.err(21261): at com.up.upload.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:149)
09-25 09:38:11.350: 
W/System.err(21261): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I suppose I'm not doing right but I know why.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

My code below:

```
    String lStr = "/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg"

    byte[] data = Base64.decode(lStr.getBytes(), 0);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    Request.addProperty("docbinaryarray", bmp);
```

Comment: You are trying to use the bytes of a string as data for a bitmap, this is very strange. Shouldn't you be opening the image at the given path ? Unless you are trying some twisted way to pass hidden data...

Comment: what are you doing? String path of image wont make a bitmap image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it completly wrong:

Use:

```
File mFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg");
if(mFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong, man. Your code only convert String, not the image data from that path. Try this:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/image.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Request.addProperty("docbinaryarray", bmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String encodeToBase64(String string)
 {
 String encodedString = "";
 try
 {
 byte[] byteData = null;
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) // Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO --> 8
    {
 byteData = android.util.Base64.encode(string.getBytes(),android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
}
else
{
 byteData = Base64Utility.encode(string.getBytes(),Base64Utility.DEFAULT);
}
 encodedString = new String(byteData);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 }
return encodedString;
}
```

If you are using api level <  8 then download Base64Utility.java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get byte array from image - try next code:

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/image.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
 File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
    if(imgFile.exists()){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
//for drawable 
        //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
```